# Sites for UML learning/reference

Tags: uml

After searching for hours on internet i am not able find sites which gives good material for  UML reference.
can any body suggest which site/book is good for UML reference?

Comment: Searching for UML reference in google gives you a ton of results, the firsts are actually quite nice. What are your expectations?

Comment: i am looking for symbol descriptions and the detailed description of each diagrams

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279662/looking-for-good-uml-tutorials

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this collection of UML cheat sheets and reference guides is what you´re looking for: http://modeling-languages.com/best-uml-cheat-sheets-and-reference-guides/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should bear in mind that UML and object-orientation - at least from point of view of software engineer - go hand in hand. You can't learn UML separate from Object oriented principles. In fact, UML is a way of representing object-oriented modeling.

Therefore, it helps a lot to learn them in parallel, since one helps to clarify the other. The book by Robert Martin, UML for Java Programers, is an excellent book that teaches both, one in light of the other.

If you are looking just for a reference book, then, Martin Fowler's "UML Distilled" is a concise and accessible reference.

Again, using UML to learn Object oriented modeling different from the case where you know OO but need a reference.

Answer (score 1):

[UML Distilled](http://www.amazon.co.uk/UML-Distilled-Standard-Modeling-Technology/dp/020165783X) by Martin Fowler is the ideal book to start with, i would also recommend [Object-Oriented Systems Analysis and Design](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Object-Oriented-Systems-Analysis-Design-Bennett/dp/0077125363/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1324896898&sr=1-3) by Simon Bennett. These two would provide a definitive guide. As well as this there are numerous UML cheat sheets online including

- [UML Quick Reference Guide](http://www.digilife.be/quickreferences/QRC/UML%20Quick%20Reference%20Card.pdf)
- [UML Reference Card](http://www.digilife.be/quickreferences/QRC/UML%20Reference%20Card.pdf)
- [UML Cheatsheet](http://loufranco.com/blog/assets/cheatsheet.pdf)